# Does `xlwings` work with Excel 64 Bit and Python 2.7 64 Bit?

Tags: xlwings

Does `xlwings` work with Excel 64 Bit and Python 2.7 64 Bit on Windows? I couldn't find any information on this on the [official site](http://xlwings.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it does. It doesn't require any specific combination - you can mix and match the bit versions of Python and Excel which is actually one of the strength of xlwings. As mentioned on the landing page of xlwings.org: "Flexible: Works with pretty much every combination of Excel and Python."

Comment: Thank you, Felix! I must have missed that. P.S. xlwings is a real nice library! Though, I only used it with Excel 32 Bit so far.